# Sitecollection has reached 2 GB storage

Tags: sharepoint-server

I would like to know how to handle a site collection that has reached 2GB allowed storage. Please let me know what is the best practice to handle this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the site collection reaches the maximum storage level,the site collection administrator can either delete unused content from the site collection or ask a member of the Farm Administrators group to increase the limits. A farm administrator can do any of the following to change the limits:

1.Change the storage limit on the quota template that the site collection is using.

2.Designate a new quota template that has a higher storage limit to the site collection. This automatically increases the limits for the site collection to the limits in the newly designated quota template. This is the preferred method, because the settings in the new quota template are automatically applied to the site collection and no additional action is needed.

3.Change the storage limit for the site collection manually. This overrides the limits set in the quota template that is currently applied to the site collection.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263480(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263480%28v=office.14%29.aspx)